# Escaping colon in ExtJS 4.1 JSON path mapping

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, escaping, mapping

I would like to know how can I escape colons in JSON path.

Here's an example of my JSON string:

```
{
"succinctProperties": {
    "cmis:objectId": "35589dd4-647f-4a6d-884f-0575d8a93127",
    "cmis:name": "35589dd4-647f-4a6d-884f-0575d8a93127",
    "cmis:createdBy": "<unknown>",
    "cmis:lastModifiedBy": "Wed Jun 05 16:26:56 CEST 2013",
    "cmis:creationDate": 1370442416100,
    "cmis:lastModificationDate": 1370442416100,
    "cmis:changeToken": null,
    "cmis:baseTypeId": "cmis:document",
    "cmis:objectTypeId": "cmis:document",
    "cmis:isImmutable": false,
    "cmis:isLatestVersion": true,
    "cmis:isMajorVersion": true,
    "cmis:isLatestMajorVersion": true,
    "cmis:versionLabel": "35589dd4-647f-4a6d-884f-0575d8a93127",
    "cmis:versionSeriesId": "version_series_id",
    "cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut": false,
    "cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy": null,
    "cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId": null,
    "cmis:checkinComment": "",
    "cmis:contentStreamLength": 210028,
    "cmis:contentStreamMimeType": "application/octet-stream",
    "cmis:contentStreamFileName": "35589dd4-647f-4a6d-884f-0575d8a93127",
    "cmis:contentStreamId": null
}
```

}

I'm trying to map keys with my ExtJS store using this as a model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.SearchDocumentModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [{name:'OBJECT_ID',type:'string',mapping:'succinctProperties.cmis:objectId'},
         {name:'NAME',type:'string',mapping:'succinctProperties.cmis:name'}  
     ]
```

});

I used several escaping methods but none of them works.

When I load this I got this as an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I used this syntax for JSON Path:

**succinctProperties["cmis:objectId"]**

```
Ext.define(MyApp.model.SearchDocumentModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [{name:'OBJECT_ID',type:'string',mapping:'succinctProperties["cmis:objectId"]'},
         {name:'NAME',type:'string',mapping:'succinctProperties["cmis:name"]'}  
     ] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the [`useSimpleAccessors`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-useSimpleAccessors) option of your reader to `true`.

Comment: I'll try this also but I already resolved my problem using another JSON path syntax. e.g:
fields:[{name:'OBJECT_ID',type:'string',mapping:'succinctProperties["cmis:objectId"]'},